# Adding max values label to plotly scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly

I have been trying all day to add max value annotation to a plotly plot. I figured out how to do it manually but I am more interested in a more automatic solution. I added my code in but omitted anything unrelated.

Is there a way to add a label to the max points of my plotly scatterplot?

P.S. Please be nice this is my first posting here.

The relevant part of the code:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

m = df['values'].max()

day_order = ['Monday',
             'Tuesday',
             'Wednesday',
             'Thursday',
             'Friday',
             'Saturday',
             'Sunday']

fig = px.scatter(df,
                 x='day-of-week',
                 y ='values',
                 category_orders = {
                     'day-of-week': day_order})

fig.add_annotation(x='Sunday', 
                   y=m,
                   text=m)
```

Comment: Trying all day, but no code to show for your efforts? Please share the attempt that you were most convinced about that it would work, and explain what the problem is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added some code, again my annotation method works but I would like to know if there is a more streamlined solution.

Comment: It is also possible to specify the day of the week and the maximum value on the y-axis. It is also possible to specify the day of the week and the maximum value on the y-axis, but the one shown below specifies the first day of the week when there is more than one maximum value, so that needs to be considered. `my_chart.add_annotation(x=df[df['values']==max(df['values'])]['day-of-week'].head(1),y=max(df['values']),text=max(df['values']))`

Comment: Hi @vvv welcome to SO! You should try to add a sample of your `df`.  It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: I edited your code. If you are using `pandas` it is better to use `df['values'].max()` instead of `max(df['values'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Used data**

[image]

**Code**: find max value and day(s) with max value and add their annotations

```
max_value = df['values'].max()
max_days = df[df['values'] == max_value]['day-of-week'].values

day_order = ['Monday',
             'Tuesday',
             'Wednesday',
             'Thursday',
             'Friday',
             'Saturday',
             'Sunday']

fig = px.scatter(df,
                 x='day-of-week',
                 y ='values',
                 category_orders = {
                     'day-of-week': day_order})

for day in max_days:
  fig.add_annotation(x=day,
                    y=max_value,
                    text=max_value)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is perfect!!

Answer (score 2):

I generate a data sample for you.

## Data

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 14
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": pd.date_range(
        start=pd.Timestamp.today().date(),
        periods=n),
     "values": np.arange(n)})

# date to day-of-week
df["day-of-week"] = df["date"].dt.day_name()

day_order = ['Monday',
             'Tuesday',
             'Wednesday',
             'Thursday',
             'Friday',
             'Saturday',
             'Sunday']

m = df["values"].max()
```

## Plot

```py
fig = px.scatter(df,
                 x='day-of-week',
                 y ='values',
                 category_orders = {
                     'day-of-week': day_order})

fig.add_annotation(x=df.iloc[df["values"].idxmax()]["day-of-week"], 
                   y=m,
                   text=str(m))
```

In the last part is important that text is a `str`

[image]